# Application of Shared Read Locks

Tags: concurrency, locking, abap

what is the need for a read shared lock?

I can understand that write locks have to be exclusive only. But what is the need for many clients to access the document simultaneously and still share only read privilege? Practical applications of Shared read locks would be of great help too.

Please move the question to any other forum you'd find it appropriate to be in.
Though this is a question purely related to ABAP programming and theory I'm doing, I'm guessing the applications are generic to all languages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do complex and time-consuming calculations based on multiple datasets (e. g. postings), you have to ensure that none of these datasets is changed while you're working - otherwise the calculations might be wrong. Most of the time, the ACID principles will ensure this, but sometimes, that's not enough - for example if the datasource is so large that you have to break it up into parallel subtasks or if you have to call some function that performs a database commit or rollback internally. In this case, the transaction isolation is no longer enough, and you need to lock the entity on a logical level.